# How to pass a column name through a variable to a function inside data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I want to apply a function to some column whose name is in a variable. I can select it with eval() but I can't pass it to a function.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(col1 = 1:10)
mnem <- colnames(dt)[1]

# This works fine
dt[, eval(mnem)]

# None of these works
dt[, sum(mnem)]
dt[, sum(mnem), with = FALSE]

dt[, sum(eval(mnem))]
dt[, sum(eval(mnem)), with = FALSE]
```

Comment: `dt[, sum(.SD), .SDcols=mnem]`

Comment: The message you'll see with "verbose" settings on and a by-group computation is "'(m)get' found in j. ansvars being set to all columns. Use .SDcols or a single j=eval(macro) instead. Both will detect the columns used which is important for efficiency." In this case, you'd perhaps do `e = substitute(sum(mnem), list(mnem = as.symbol("col1"))); dt[, eval(e)]`. Fyi, FAQ 1.6 has more regarding eval https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html

Comment: @user2957945 Yeah, though the usual convention is `lapply(.SD, sum)` instead of `sum(.SD)`.

Comment: user2957945 & Frank probably right in that you're likely looking for `.SDcols` combined with `lapply(.SD, FUN)`

Comment: @Frank interesting... I guess that means [#1744](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1744) is (sort-of) documented after all?

Comment: @MichaelChirico Thanks for pointing it out. I had totally missed the connection. :)

Answer (score 0):

Folks have said the right answer, alternatively you can do:

```
dt[, sum(eval(parse(text = mnem)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

@"R for the Win"'s form is useful (necessary?) for producing summaries with meaningful column headings for the grouping variable(s).

```
mtcarsDT <- setDT(copy(mtcars))
makeSummaryTable <- function(dt, measure, group){
  dt[,.(N = .N, avg = mean(get(measure)), med = median(get(measure)))
    , by = eval(text = group)][order(get(group))]
}
makeSummaryTable(mtcars, 'qsec', 'am')
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but I do this all the time. Try this code:

```
dt[, sum(get(mnem))]
```

Alternatively, you can try:

```
dt[, sum(.SD), .SDcols = vector_col_names]
```